# Teradata: condition on a char variable

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to do this:

```
select * from table 
WHERE report_date = '31.08.2017'
```

report_date is CHAR variable and i'm getting Error 3535 (character string failed conversion to a numeric value)
How should I change my query?

sry for noobish question

Comment: That error indicates the report_date column has a numerical data type.

Comment: Doesn't Teradata have a date data type?

Answer (score 0):

Teradata handle date literals in either teradata format `'YY/MM/DD'` or `ANSI` format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. The `ANSI DATE` literal form `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'` does not depend on format setting or default.

In this case, you correct query will look like

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE report_date = '2017-08-31';
```

The above will work regardless of transaction mode i.e. `ANSI/BTET`

However if your `date` column is of `CHAR` data type and data is stored as `'31.08.2017'` i.e. `DD.MM.YYYY`, you need to manually cast it to `date` using `to_date`.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE to_date(report_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = to_date('31.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

or just right side as below.

```
select * 
from TABLE
WHERE report_date =  to_date('31.08.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

or using `cast`

```
select * 
from table
WHERE cast(report_date as date) =  cast('31.08.2017' as date format 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```